# Is it impossible for clinical and laboratory data to be normally distributed?

Tags: distributions

Because all clinical and laboratory data are continuous random variables larger than zero (i.e. they are bounded above zero), is it impossible for them to be normally distributed? Can they only be log-normally distributed?
Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the lognormal family there are many other common distributions with positive essential support: gamma, Weibull, F, half-normal, etc.  Moreover, *no* distribution is truly "continuous" if you're going to be this strict about definitions: your measurements must be real numbers with finite representations and as such are necessarily *discrete*!

Answer (score 9):

You are correct, a positive-only value cannot be *really* normally distributed. However depending on the particular circumstances, its distribution could be sufficiently close to normal for statistical methodology assuming normality to apply. I want to note that very few methods actually require normality of the *data*, often only model residuals, or sampling distributions have to be (approximately) normally distributed.

Answer (score 3):

Many biological measurements take positive values only and to such variables applies the rule of thumb: *If $\text{mean} < 2\cdot\text{SD}$ then the distribution is not normal*.

Explanation: for normally distributed values the majority of values are in the interval $[\text{mean}\pm2\cdot\text{SD}]$, and a normal distribution with $\text{mean} < 2\cdot\text{SD}$ would have a too large proportion of negative values, the normal approximation is poor. Of course be cautious like with any other rules of thumb.